# From (every / any / all) angles

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, adverbs, collocations

Could anyone possibly let me know which collocation below sounds better in English?

> - Apparently, you have decided to cooperate with them! Your manager don't seem to be a reliable person. Well, even though I don't like you to work there, just make sure you have considered your contract .............before signing it.

**a.** from *every* angle 
**b.** from *any* angle 
**c.** from *all* angle**s**

I wonder whether all the three choices above could be used in the blank. 
Do they all sound correct to you both grammatically and semantically? 
If no, then why?

To me, 'a' and 'b' are quite interchangeable and 'c' has a slight nuance compared to the former two options. Also, I find nothing wrong with each choice above and I think they are all correct and can be used in the sentence with more or less the same meaning.

Comment: Angles in the title, aspects in the question. Which do you mean?

Comment: (a) and (c) mean the same. (b) implies that the speaker doesn't think the person has considered the contract at all (have they even considered one aspect of it?).

Comment: Sorry, I meant "angle" @Michael Harvey. I fixed my thread.

Comment: I'm so sorry @Kate Bunting. May I ask you for changing your answer. I made a mistake when I was posting my question.

Comment: The gist of my comment is the same whether you say _aspect_ or _angle_!

Comment: Thank you very much for the response @Kate Bunting. Just may I ask you whether the collocation "any angle/aspect" is a valid combination or it is totally a wrong one?

Comment: Note "even though I don't like you to work there" is not good English. Instead: "...I wouldn't like you working there" or "I don't like you working there" (depending on if the person has started already or not).

Answer (score 1):

As Kate said in the comments, **from every angle** and **from all angles** are exact synonyms and would be interchangeable in any context I can think of—including your context here. They mean exactly what the sound like: a *complete 360° view* of the situation, that is, considering every possible outcome.

**From *any* angle** is different, because it requires only one single angle (=outcome) instead of all of them. This would be used if the questioner wants to know if you have considered the situation *at all*, that is, from *even one* of the many angles. It would not make sense in the structure of your context.

Comment: Well, how about "from any **angles / aspect**" @randomhead?

Comment: **From any angles/aspects** is not idiomatic in this context.